# To check whether given set is compact set

Tags: compactness

why $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$ with product topology ,where ${A_n=\{0,1\}}$  has discrete topology for n=1,2,3,...   is compact set?

I know that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$  ,where ${A_n=\{0,1\}}$  is uncountable set and is complete as it do not  have cauchy sequence but how to check for totally bounded

I am not getting any direction to solve this problem

Comment: Because the product of compact sets is compact ... ?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the Tychonoff theorem, which states that the product of compact spaces, endowed with the product topology is compact. Since in this case you have a countable product of metrizable compact spaces, you don't even need the Axiom of choice to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $A_n$ is compact (Why?). Now use the Tychonoff theorem to say that the product is compact.